# Pinging different IP address than what I entered

Tags: networking, ip, ping, cmd.exe, ip-address

Can anyone please explain why CMD pings a different IP address than the one I am searching for?

[image: Example]

Comment: This is a duplicate, I just can't remember where

Comment: @DavidPostill, It's not a duplicate, because in the question you linked to, the system was treating numbers with and without leading zeroes as decimal, but in this question, it's pretty clear the system is interpreting leading zeroes as octal numbers.

Comment: @SamSkuce Did you read the highest voted answer? "For example, if you use a 3-digit number starting with a zero (or a two-digit one starting with zero, ... ), then ping will assume the numbers are octal."

Comment: As well, when we suggest a duplicate post, the OP is asked to look at the question *and answers* to see if it's the same

Answer (score 45):

On Windows CMD if you put leading zeros on the IP address means **octal**.

It is interpreting `016` as `16 octal` and converts it to `14 decimal`.

You can use *octal, decimal or hexadecimal* notation as in the following example:

```
22.101.31.153 (decimal)
026.0145.037.0231 (octal)
0x16.0x65.0xF1.0x99 (hexadecimal)
```

Comment: neat. did not know that.

Comment: Wow. That is a _terrible_ [undocumented "feature"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115388). Turns out Chrome does it also (`4.4.4.8` and `4.4.4.010` are equivalent)

Comment: Well BEEP, it works with hex too! That makes the old `ping 10.1000001` look almost sane... `ping 10.0xDEAD` ... !!!

Comment: It's neither terrible, nor undocumented; [this is the regular notation for IPv4 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Addressing)

Comment: @sebleblanc No, it's rather bad, since it differentiates between a leading zero and nothing, which a lot of implementations will not think to consider. It's a potential failure point with little upside, as octal is already rarely used--especially in this context. (Yes, the problem is with leading 0 octal notation in the first place, which should have been filtered out of modern languages, converted to something like leading 8x or something.)

Comment: @trlkly so you're disappointed MS is following the standard?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor No. I think the standard itself is bad. I think leading 0 octal notation is bad. And while I'm glad Microsoft followed the standard, I'd prefer it be buried behind a switch for usability purposes, or at least some information being given to say that a specific number is  being read as octal, and you should leave out the 0 if you don't want that.

Comment: You can also skip zeroes. Try pinging 10.1, 192.168.1, and 127.1 (depending on your network, at least two of these should ping). I happened across this a while back, and it confused me briefly. I guess it's cool that we can do all kinds of shorthand, but I'd rather be forced to at least specify what I'm doing as intentional.

Comment: @phyrfox I suppose there's very little downside to accidentally pinging the wrong ip. And the ping tells you what it's pinging

Comment: The people handling IP addresses should understand what they are before using them. Leading zero octal notation is common enough that it is a mistake you will only do once. End users typically are not expected to handle IP addresses, or at least, they should not alter the representation. If the manual for your router says "connect to 172.16.0.1", you should not type in "172.016.000.001".