# What could cause ping command to respond from a different IP-address on local network?

Tags: windows, ping, ip-address

(This issue is on a 64-bit Windows 7 Professional)

This is similar to [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/894303/pinging-different-ip-address-than-what-i-entered), but in my case I was not preceding any of the IP-address numbers with a zero (so the answer from that question is not applicable).

In this case I pinged the IP-address 192.168.0.18 in an attempt to locate my network printer.

For some reason though the ping command response stated that it was from 192.168.0.8.

It looked like as shown below, or in this screenshot

[image]

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping 192.168.0.18

Pinging 192.168.0.18 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.0.8: Destination host unreachable. Request timed out.

Reply from 192.168.0.8: Destination host unreachable.

Reply from 192.168.0.8: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.18:

    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 3, Lost = 1 (25% loss),
```

What could cause the response to be returned from a different IP-address?

Comment: 1) Is this your own IP address? 2) If not, is your computer at least on the same subnet? 3) If they're on the same subnet, does `arp -a` show the correct MAC address for the printer? 4) What devices are there in between (routers, wireless "extenders", etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your local host or local router is 192.168.0.8, and it is telling you that it has no Layer-2 path to the host.

When your system detects that it cannot possibly send the ping frames, it itself responds to the console to tell you that the remote host's MAC address cannot be found.

See the answer here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110622/ping-response-request-timed-out-vs-destination-host-unreachable

Comment: ah yes I did find out after you wrote this that my own PCs IP is indeed 192.168.0.8. So there was a rather simple answer in the end. Thank you Frank Thomas